# Scroll-to-top WebView in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, scroll

Is there a way to make a floating button auto-scrolling to the top of a WebView and not a ListView with flutter?
This is the simple one-page flutter code where WebView is being used.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';   

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  WebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: SafeArea(
       child : WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
        child : Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget> [
                WebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://google.com",
                  zoomEnabled: false,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller){
                    webViewController = controller;
                  },
               
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll to top with WebViewController
and floating button only visible after a little scroll

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp>  {
  late WebViewController _controller;
  bool buttonshow = false;


 

  void scrollToTop(){
    _controller.runJavascript("window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});");
    floatingButtonVisibility();
  }

  void floatingButtonVisibility() async {
    int y = await  _controller.getScrollY();
    if(y>50){
      setState(() {
        buttonshow = true;
      });
    }else {
      setState(() {
        buttonshow = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
      ),
      body:  WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller = webViewController;
          },
          gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(
                Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(() => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onDown = (tap) {
                    floatingButtonVisibility();
                  }))

      ),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: buttonshow,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            scrollToTop();
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me. Please Is there a way to show that button until we scroll a little bit in the page and not from the first time. Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me

Comment: Sorry if I bothered you, but please do you know how we can animate that scrolling. I'm Really sorry. I added _controller.scrollTo(0, 0).animateTo(); but they give me this error : The method 'animateTo' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.

Comment: i updated the code : i think you need a smooth scroll up. i changed scrollTo(0,0) to     _controller.runJavascript("window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});"); and enable javascript by adding javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you. Thank you so much